# Leaflet.js custom editable markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, leaflet

is it possible to make my own markers to look like road signs, with text boxes in them? I want my users to have the ability to enter text in them (which is gonna be saved via ajax when "blur" event fires).

Comment: I think that the Easyest way to make this is to Had popup on your map (you can custom them by pure CSS) and also had html code (like a input).

Answer (score 1):

Consult the [Leaflet reference documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html): you can do this with the L.divIcon class.